# Set transaction manager for Imap Idle Channel Adapter in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to set up transactional behaviour for email messages which received by ImapIdleChannelAdapter. After transaction commit i want to delete message from e-mail. I have set up my Mail Recevier Configuration in such way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "email")
@Profile("email")
public class MailReceiverConfiguration {

    @Setter
    private String imapUsername;

    @Setter
    private String imapPassword;

    @Setter
    private String imapServer;

    @Setter
    private String imapServerPort;

    @Setter
    private String folder;

    @Setter
    private String storeProtocol;

    @Bean(name = "emailTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager emailTransactionManager() {
        PseudoTransactionManager pseudoTransactionManager = new PseudoTransactionManager();
        pseudoTransactionManager.getTransactionSynchronization();
        return pseudoTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel receiveChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapIdleChannelAdapter(ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver) {
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapIdleChannelAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(imapMailReceiver);
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(receiveChannel());
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory());

        return imapIdleChannelAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ImapMailReceiver receiver = new ImapMailReceiver(
            storeProtocol + "://" + URLEncoder.encode(imapUsername, "UTF-8") + ":" + imapPassword + "@" + imapServer + ":" + imapServerPort + "/" + folder
    );
        receiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
        receiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
        return receiver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

        ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor syncProcessor =
            new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
        syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(parser.parseExpression("@messagesDeleter.process(payload)"));

        return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);
        }

        @Bean
        public MessagesDeleter messagesDeleter() {
            return new MessagesDeleter();
        }

}
```

Bean MessageDeleter have void method to set flag deleted to message:

```
public class MessagesDeleter{

public void process(MimeMessage message) throws Exception{
    Folder folder = message.getFolder();
    String messageId = message.getMessageID();
    Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        if (((MimeMessage) messages[i]).getMessageID().equals(messageId)) {
            messages[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
            break;
        }
    }
    folder.close(true);
}
```

I try to do all like in [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html). I receive messages, but transactions doesn't exists. I found that in ImapIdleChannelAdapter in method `createMessageSendingTask(final Object mailMessage)` when break at checking of `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` it return `false`. How i can add liked TransactionManager or include it. Or what i make wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct with the `imapIdleChannelAdapter.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory());`.

What you are missing is the fact to add a `TransactionInterceptor` into the `imapIdleChannelAdapter.setAdviceChain()`:

```
imapIdleChannelAdapter.setAdviceChain(
                 Collections.singletonList(
                        new TransactionInterceptorBuilder()
                              .transactionManager(emailTransactionManager())
                              .build()))
```

**UPDATE**

Before Spring Integration `5.0` you need to configure a `TransactionInterceptor` manually:

```
TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor = new TransactionInterceptor();
MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource txAttributeSource = new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource();
txAttributeSource.setTransactionAttribute(new DefaultTransactionAttribute());
transactionInterceptor.setTransactionAttributeSource(txAttributeSource);
transactionInterceptor.setTransactionManager(emailTransactionManager());
```

Comment: Thanks! i think it is what i miss, but I use Spring 4.x. So i wrote code like this, but get exception: `Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:271)
`. `TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor = new TransactionInterceptor();
        transactionInterceptor.setTransactionManager(emailTransactionManager());

        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(transactionInterceptor));`

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My message flow contains stage of handling message. I use method `void receiveMessageAndHandleIt()` marked with `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "receiveChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "200"))`. But transaction commit before handling message in this method. What should i add to include this stage to transaction? Or i have to process message in BeforeTransaction method in Sync Processor?

Comment: Your problem that you use there a `QueueChannel` in between. Therefore you move message to another thread, meanwhile transactions work in the thread boundaries.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. WIth `DirectChannel` everuthing works fine!