# MessageRemovedException on mailParsing when setShouldMarkAsDelete flag true in IMAP IDLE Adaptor config

Tags: spring-integration

I am getting the MessageRemovedException on parsing the email after receiving the email in the EmailReceiveChannel, if I have configure ShouldMarkAsDelete flag as "true".
Everything works fine if the flag is set as false

```
@Bean
    public ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver() {

        StringBuilder impaURI = new StringBuilder();
        impaURI.append(MAIL_PROTOCOL).append("://").append(MAIL_USERNAME).append(":").append(MAIL_PASSWORD)
        .append("@").append(MAIL_HOST).append(":").append(MAIL_PORT).append("/").append(MAIL_FOLDER);
        
        ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(impaURI.toString());
        mailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(true);
        mailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
        mailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
        mailReceiver.setAutoCloseFolder(false);

        return mailReceiver;
    }
```

On debugging the flow, expunged flag for MimeMessage is coming as "true". This stopped working recently.
Any idea why is this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The logic there in the `AbstractMailReceiver` is like this:

```
private void postProcessFilteredMessages(Message[] filteredMessages) throws MessagingException {
    setMessageFlags(filteredMessages);

    if (shouldDeleteMessages()) {
        deleteMessages(filteredMessages);
    }
```

where that `deleteMessages()` does only this:

```
message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
```

The `expunge` functionality is performed over here:

```
protected void closeFolder() {
    this.folderReadLock.lock();
    try {
        MailTransportUtils.closeFolder(this.folder, this.shouldDeleteMessages);
    }
    finally {
        this.folderReadLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

So, since you have that `mailReceiver.setAutoCloseFolder(false);`, it means you close folder yourself and only after that you try to get access to the message content. Must be opposite: you have to close folder only after you have already parsed the content of the message.

Comment: Setting autoCloseFolder(true) is throwing the below exception `2022-04-29 | 15:10:00.162 | taskScheduler-17                         |  WARN | o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        | error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while copying message`

Comment: I also tried implementing the transaction Management as mentioned in the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415482/set-transaction-manager-for-imap-idle-channel-adapter-in-spring" but keep on getting exception `EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'messagesDeleter`

Comment: Well, I mean keep that ` mailReceiver.setAutoCloseFolder(false);` - you need it to be able to get access to the content of the message. What bothers me that you perhaps close the folder too early. How do you parse the content and how do you close the folder?

Comment: I don't think I am closing the Folder anywhere in my custom code. I have a service Activator which receives the Email message and then delegates it to a service API for Parsing. `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "emailReceiveChannel", poller = @Poller(value = "emailPoller"))` and in this activator I am delegating it to a service `getEmailReceiverService().processEmailMessage(message);`

Comment: How do you use that `imapMailReceiver()`? According to the code logic that `expunge` is only possible when we close the folder. This or other way. Therefore I want to determine your logic. What Spring Integration version do you use, too?

Comment: This is a Spring Boot application and Spring Integration version is 5.5.1. ImapAdaptorConfig is in the main question. As per my requirement I just have to read the email messages, process it to send the attachments to other applications and mark the emails for deletion as we get huge number of emails.

Comment: OK. FYI `5.5.11` is the latest. How do you use that `imapMailReceiver()` anyway, please?

Comment: My full IMAP Adaptor configuration is in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878451/spring-boot-imap-channel-adapter-is-losing-emails-while-processing-a-large-numbe

Comment: I don't think that config is actual since we had with you some discussion over there and it looks like you did some changes.

Comment: The `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` has this option: `private Executor sendingTaskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);`. As you see it is only `1` by default. This might the reason why it is stuck processing. Just because the parsing is too slow.

Comment: You may consider to inject some custom executor or use a `SyncTaskExecutor` to block an `idle` loop for polling more messages from the folder. Also see `AbstractMailReceiver.maxFetchSize` do not pull too much from the mail server.

Comment: Hi Artem, the email adaptor config is same. As per your suggestions I only made change to decrease the size of message per poll from 100 to 5

Comment: Ok. So, consider, please, my new suggestions re. `SyncTaskExecutor`  and `maxFetchSize`. I still don't like to have that `QueueChannel` in between. You indeed may lose messages.

Comment: Sure. I will try removing the Queue channel as well.

Comment: I have updated the config to use the DirectChannel and also set the ImapReceiver's MaxFetchSize to 10 and updated Imap Adaptor with new taskexecutor; `imapAdapter.setSendingTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));`. Still the code is failing at the first line on parsing the email message with FolderClosedException

Comment: The folder Close exception is always there now irrespective of ShouldDeleteMessageFlag is set to true or false

Comment: Do you still use ` mailReceiver.setAutoCloseFolder(false);` ?

Comment: Yes I am `mailReceiver.setAutoCloseFolder(false);`

Comment: Did you try to use a `SyncTaskExecutor` for that `setSendingTaskExecutor()`? Otherwise I'm out of ideas and would like to ask you to share with us some simple project to play with. Something is definitely off and nothing gives a clue yet why your folder is closed.

Comment: Is there any server side settings in the mailbox itself which can cause this problem. I enabled debug logs as well but couldn't figure out anything. Also the same code is deployed in production where we are encountering the issue with the bulk emails but this particular issue is not observed. this is happening in lower environment after I made some code changes to test the bulk upload problem and that code changes are not related to ImpaAdaptors

Comment: I have updated the ImapAdaptor to use SyncTaskExecutor and it worked `imapAdapter.setSendingTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());`

Comment: So, the problem turns out to be with the thread shifting and loosing a folder context?

Comment: I am still debugging and not sure which piece of code has introduced this problem. Is this a standard behavior?  The same code with all the QueueChannels and all is working in Prod.

Comment: Perhaps you don’t have so many messages over there. Or Spring Integration version is different …

Comment: I have updated the Spring Boot to the latest and that updated the Spring integration version to 5.5.11. Also now I am getting the same FolderClosedException with SyncTaskExecutor as well.. 2nd and 3rd email both failed

Comment: How does it work if you change your `QueueChannel` for the `DirectChannel` as an output of this IMAP channel adapter? I'm thinking now about removal that `setSendingTaskExecutor()` functionality altogether: it is better to process fetched messages in the fetching thread - don't pull more and don't lose them in case of crash...

Comment: Yes I made the exact changes to test the behavior. On debugging what I figured out, that when the message is received in my Service class its `expunged` flag is set to false but when I call the parse method of the `MimeMessageParser` the `expunged` method get sets to true and then the parser throws and exception `MessageRemovedException` from `checkExpunged()` method. This is how I am instantiating the MimeMessageParser `MimeMessageParser mailParser = new MimeMessageParser((MimeMessage) message);`

Comment: I also set maxfetchsize to 1 just to test this flow

Comment: Yeah... That's why I'm asking about simple project to reproduce and play with. Not sure if my own app is going to help you somehow or I would have the same configuration as you do

Comment: I am able to parse the message after I implemented the transaction management as explained in  Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415482/set-transaction-manager-for-imap-idle-channel-adapter-in-spring. This change stopped the issue with the expunged Flag. But now I am getting exception in the message clean up event. '`Creating EvaluationContext with no beanFactory
java.lang.RuntimeException: No beanFactory` for this line `syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(parser.parseExpression("@messagesDeleter.process(payload)"));`

Comment: That `SyncProcessor` has to be declared as a bean

Comment: Thanks. That fixes this problem. now back to Bulk mail problem

Comment: What is that one remind me , please?

Comment: So, In a normal situation the application is working as expected. But on two weekdays downstream system sends more than 15000 (sometimes 20000) emails at once. During this time application loses email (some thousands) and then we have to reconcile the system that what is left to integrate

Comment: Right. That's why I suggest do not use a `QueueChannel` in between and use that `SyncTaskExecutor` for IMAP producer.

Comment: Yes. But on changing the Queue to DirectChannel, the processing slows down a lot.

Comment: You can switch to another thread when you are already done with the email parsing. The point is to keep email folder context in a single thread to avoid data loss.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am testing now. I have made the whole handling process as `async` after parsing the email content.

Comment: So, I have updated the mail Receiver `mailReceiver.setMaxFetchSize(1);`, added `imapAdapter.setSendingTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());` to ImapAdaptor and declared my processAttachments function as `@Async`. This change definitely speeds up the processing and all the service calls are happening in Parallel (tested with 3 emails). The issue then happens in the `messageDeleter` function which is a part of the transaction handling and setting the Delete flag in message. Exception I am getting is `B36 NO Some of the requested messages no longer exist.`

Comment: That's not correct. You cannot remove messages from the folder until you process them fully. As long as you shift parsing to another process (`@Async`), the transaction is committed and therefore message is removed from the folder (if you use a deleter you mention from that SO thread). What I mean is do not close the folder until all the messages are processed and do not shift the "hard" work to different thread.

Comment: I am completely parsing the email message in `ServiceActivator` and retrieve whatever information I need from email and then sending those  data to the `async` handling. So at the time I am delegating the processing I no longer need the message object.

Comment: Sounds good. So, looks like you don't need transaction then!

Comment: yup I just disabled the transactions